# Is this an acceptable way to accept a one-time payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

On my site I'm giving users the option to save their card or not. If they choose to save it, I'm creating a Stripe customer object, and if not, I'm just saving the card token, and when it comes time to pay, if they have a Stripe Customer id then I charge that way, and if not, I charge the tokenized card.

There could be cases where a week or so passes before I would charge the card token. Would it still work, and is there anything else wrong with this setup?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe Tokens are meant to be used within a short period of time from when they are created and should not be stored. 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens

If you are not charging the token immediately, I would recommend attaching it to a Customer in that scenario as well.

Comment: thanks - and then I would delete the customer once the transaction is complete, correct?

Comment: yes, if it is only a one-time payment, you can safely delete the customer